# Gradle Enterprise cache misses because dependency name changes on each build

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-enterprise

I have cache misses in my Gradle build (with Gradle Enterprise enabled), because the name of one dependency changes on each build. It's one of the modules in the project, but the name of the generated jar is controlled by Jenkins. This is how the dependency is defined in my project:

```
compile project(':my-module')
```

On each build, Jenkins adds the build number in the name of the jar and it's something I can't change.

I want to change the way the hash key is generated for this dependency, the name of the dependency should be ignored when calculating hash key. I've read docs about inputs normalization, but I can't find any examples explaining how to use it. I only managed to find an example showing how to exclude a dependency from hash calculation, but that is something I want to avoid (when someone makes a change in that module, the hash should change).